# iOS AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat overrides AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

If I set up my category to allowBluetooth devices, then call setMode, the allowBluetooth flag gets cleared, even though that's a direct discrepancy with iOS documentation. Anyone seen a workaround for this or have another suggestion on how to get VoiceChat mode AND allowBluetooth set?

Code looks like this:

```
//set the category
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                error: &setCategoryError];

if (!success) {
    /* handle the error in setCategoryError */
    NSLog(@"Set category error %@", setCategoryError);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Set category success %@ %lu %@", [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] category], (unsigned long)[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] categoryOptions], [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] mode]);
}

NSError *setModeError = nil;
success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
                error:&setModeError];

if (!success) {
    /* handle the error in setModeError */
    NSLog(@"Set mode error %@", setModeError);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Set mode success %@ %lu %@", [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] category], (unsigned long)[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] categoryOptions], [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] mode]);
}
```

Logs look like this:

> 2015-07-24 14:55:19.945 audioTest[1681:679757] Set category success AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 4 AVAudioSessionModeDefault
>   2015-07-24 14:55:19.946 audioTest[1681:679757] Set mode success AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 0 AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat

Notice that "4" is the AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth option and "0" is "no options set"